# Same slot types working differently on AWS LEX V1 and V2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, alexa-slot

I have a custom slot types called amount in which i added decimals, whole numbers, numbers with dollar sign and numbers with comman, alphanumeric strings with dollar text such as "Two dollar thirty cents", "2 dollar 30 cents".

Now for 1 intent it is working fine. If i type 10000, it will accept it
But for other intent, if I type 10000, it does not accept it.

Also most of the time it is accepting the same value which i feed in expand value option in custom slot type Ex., if I feed 8345 to custom slot type, the slots will accept input for 8345 only, if I enter any other 4 digit number, it gives error.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Have a look at this comment that proposes using an AWS-provided custom grammar file to capture the amount. It looks like a pretty good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71715351/8880593

Comment: @Reegz thank you for the suggestion but we already looked at this option. Please correct me if i am wrong, currently grammer slot type can be used in english us, uk and au locales, but along with english us, we want solution for spanish, chinese, korean, portuges and japanese locale as well. Is there any solution for amount for these locales?

Comment: I've never tried another language but I imagine you should be able to take one of those samples and extend it for your desired languages. From a quick scan of it, my guess would be changing the language `xml:lang="en-US"` and the currency type: `<rule id="currency">`

Comment: ohh let me try with this.

Comment: @Reegz an update, we cant even add a grammer slot type in different locales, no option for adding grammer slot type in console for spanish language. Even i tried exporting it and editing in json and then importing it back, got an error slot type not supported for es_ES locale,

Comment: I believe a valid value for locale would be: `es-ES`
It's dash and not underscore.

Comment: @Reegz sure will try to do that. One more question I have raised it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72646037 , bot is not recognizing voice utterance properly, is there any way to do it?